# Listview Items to another form's textbox

Tags: vb.net

> My first form is **frmBlotterAddEdit**

*This is my code in my 2nd form*

```
Private Sub lvmembers_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lvmembers.MouseDoubleClick
    frmBlotterAddEdit.txtFirst.Text = lvmembers.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text()
    frmBlotterAddEdit.txtMid.Text = lvmembers.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text()
    frmBlotterAddEdit.txtLast.Text = lvmembers.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text()
    frmBlotterAddEdit.txtHouse.Text = lvmembers.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text()
    frmBlotterAddEdit.txtStreet.Text = lvmembers.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text()
    frmBlotterAddEdit.txtBlock.Text = lvmembers.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(6).Text()

    Dim frm As New frmBlotterAddEdit
    frm.GroupBox1.Refresh()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

When I double click the list view, nothing happens.

Comment: What would you like to happen? Your first 6 lines of code appear to be referring to the default instance of the class. Do you not want to be using 'frm' instead?

Comment: I want the subsets of the listview to pass to the frmBlotterAddEdit's textboxes.

Comment: Did you create and launch your second form from an instance of frmBlotterAddEdit? frmBlotterAddEdit.txtFirst <- this won't pass data to your first form, it'll pass it to the default instance of your first form. Dim frm As New frmBlotterAddEdit <- this will create yet another instance, and won't refer to your original first form.

Comment: Can you please show me how its done?

Comment: Show the code that creates and shows your 2nd form.

Comment: **frmBlotterBrowse.ShowDialog()** this one.

Comment: Ok, so in the mousedoubleclick, instead of 'me.close', just hide the form. Then back in your first form, after frmblotterbrowse.showdialog, pull the values from frmblotterbrowse.lvmembers.etc into your first form. Then dispose the 2nd form.

Comment: Can you please show me how its done? Im lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the 2nd form in your MouseDoubleClick event. Then do your processing back in your first form.

2nd form:

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDoubleClick
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

1st form:

```
Private Sub Show2ndFormButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Show2ndFormButton.Click

    Try

        Dim f2 As New Form2
        f2.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = f2.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
        f2.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Andrew! God bless you.